# Can I define a length for a JFormattedText?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

So for example, how could I create a mask for a house number? I could use `JFormattedText` with '####' but that would define my text to have 4 digits, and on the contrary if I use `JTextField`, it would need some scripts and procedures to verify while the user is writing. So the point is if there is a middle solution. Like a mask saying only numbers AND with length 1 to 3, 4, n...

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you have a length of 4, will that no also accept a length of 1, 2 or 3? Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yeah, imagine like this. You create a JFormattedText and goes to Properties->formatterFactory->mask->Format, set it to "####", so this #### means 4 only numbers, which is exactly 4 digits. If you input "321" and go the next field, your JFormattedText will erase it and set it to a value "null"(as it will be blank with any other sign you assigned to the mask). There is no extra code or examples except when the program is running which gives what is described.

Comment: What I've done is verify on the event KeyType the size of the length of this field and if what is typed is a number. I changed too from JFormatted to JText since it won't need a mask with others signs

Comment: (1-) Where is your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. You made a statement that it doesn't work, so post your code showing what you tried so we don't have to guess what you are doing. Every question should have an `MCVE`!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use inputMethodTextChanged for the JTextField.
Catch the input and format to anything you want!
There are detail to formattedtextfield:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did what I sayd on the comments on top. The JFormattedtextField on the documentation didn't said much about length, so particularly for this case it was best to switch to a JTextField

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `NumberFormatter` to the `JFormattedTextField`. There you can set minimum, maximum values and set value class to be `Interger.class`.

Answer (score 0):

this should be settable in [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)  with [setMaximumIntegerDigits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumIntegerDigits(int)), because you can associate a customized format with a formatted text field by using the [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) constructor that takes a `Format` as an argument.

Here in an example for your situation:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(4);
JFormattedTextField houseNumber = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
houseNumber.setValue("input");
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you input "321" and go the next field, your JFormattedText will erase it

Set the focus lost behaviour:

```
MaskFormatter format1 = new MaskFormatter("****");
format1.setValidCharacters("123456789");
JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField( format1 );
textField1.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
```